# Sequence of continuous linear operators from a normed vector space to a Banach space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

In their "Introduction to Topology" (Second Edition), 7.6 Theorem, TW Gamelin and RE Greene teach us that if a sequence of operators ${T_n}$, as titled, has a uniformly bounded norm and converges on a dense subset of its domain space $\chi$ then it converges at any point of $\chi$. The linearity of $T$ is clear.  If $x$ is confined to a unit ball on $\chi$, then $T$ is bounded and $\vert\vert{T}\vert\vert \leq \limsup \vert\vert T_n\vert\vert$. 
Now G&G turn attention to elements of a subsequence of the norm of ${T_n}$. Though the existence of $\lim{T_nx}$ has been shown and from continuity of the norm that of $\lim\vert\vert T_nx\vert\vert$ as well, we do not have the existence of $\lim\vert\vert T_n\vert\vert$, as far as I can see.  The authors choose a subsequence $n_j$ over which the $\lim\vert\vert {T_n}_j\vert\vert = \liminf\vert\vert {T_n}_j\vert\vert$. Now, I confess confusion.  My  understanding is that a bounded, non-convergent sequence is bounded *below* by liminf after a finite number of elements.  In the present case, G&G tell us that the liminf is an upper bound for $\vert\vert T\vert\vert$.
Would someone please clarify for me?

Comment: It's difficult to know without seeing the proof as written, but it sounds like it could be a typo. Maybe the liminf should have been a limsup? Do they use the fact that it's a liminf anywhere else?

Comment: The authors use the second estimate, with the liminf, in the proof of the next theorem, "7.7 Theorem".   I believe the first estimate on the norm of $T$ would also work for this case.

Comment: You say they *choose* such a subsequence - the fact that $\{\|T_n\|\}$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers guarantees that there exists a subsequence $\{n_j\}$ such that $\|T_{n_j}\|$ converges. It is a slightly strange way of writing it, though.